Send scheduled push notifications in a kivy android app with background services?
I am new to this. I have a little bit knowlegde of python, but android development and kivy is pretty new to me. So i wrote this very small kivy application with nice look and a Text Label. Now I want that the app takes a message out of a list of messages and sends it per push notification every day random in a time range from 8 am to 8 pm. Also, when it sends the notification it should update the Label in the app, that it displays it until the day is over (12 pm) and then turn it back to tree dots. I thought maybe that can work with android background services, but idk how to do anything of that. Here is my kivy app code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
import random

class RememberMe(App):
        def build(self):
            
            Window.clearcolor = (1,0.89,1,1)
            layout = FloatLayout()
            
            logo = Image(source='logo.png',  pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.9})
            
            pick_random = str(random.randint(1,10))
            random_sticker = 'sticker' + pick_random + '.png'
            sticker = Image(source=random_sticker, pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}, size_hint=(0.6,0.6))
            
            bubble = Image(source='bubble.png', pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.45}, size_hint=(0.9,0.9))
            
            message = Label(text='...', color=(0,0,0,1), bold=True, pos_hint={'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.46}, text_size=(layout.width * 8, None), halign='center')
        
            layout.add_widget(sticker)
            layout.add_widget(bubble)
            layout.add_widget(message)
            layout.add_widget(logo)
            
            return layout
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RememberMe().run()

I havent tried much, because i dont have a clue about buildozer yet, and all of the code i have written, i wrote in pydroid 3 on my phone. Anyone knows what i could do?
